# how to show that random variable is almost surely finite? Coin toss problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Consider the Coin toss problem, i.e. let $Z_{i} : \Omega \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ with
$$
Z_{i}\left(\omega\right) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }\omega = H\\
0 & \text{if } \omega = T
\end{cases}
$$
be the outcome of the $i$-th coin toss with $\Omega = \{H,T\}$. Assume all the $Z_{i}$ are independent and identical distributed with
$$
\mathbb{P}(Z_{i} = 1) = \mathbb{P}(Z_{i} = 0) = \frac{1}{2}.
$$
Now define
$$
R := \min \{k\geq 1 \mid Z_{k} = 1,Z_{k+1} = 0,Z_{k+2} = 1, Z_{k+3} = 0\}.
$$
$R$ is the number of tosses to get the pattern HTHT.

My question ist how to show that $R$ is almost surely finite. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Show that $$A_k := \{Z_{4k}=0, Z_{4k+1}=1, Z_{4k+2}=0, Z_{4k+3}=1\}$$ satisfies $\mathbb{P}(A_k) = 1/16$ for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
2. Show that the events $A_k$, $k \geq 1$, are independent.
3. It follows from Step 1 that $$\sum_{k \geq 1} \mathbb{P}(A_k) = \infty.$$ Apply the Borel Cantelli lemma (using Step 2) to conclude that $$\mathbb{P}(A_k \, \, \text{infinitely often})=1.$$
4. Conclude that $\mathbb{P}(R<\infty)=1$.

Comment: Is this correct? $\mathbb{P}(R = \infty) = \mathbb{P}(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\inf A_{n}^{c}) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(A_{n}~~ \text{infinitely often}) = 0$

Comment: I'm sorry. Now see my comment

Comment: @love_math It **is** correct that $\mathbb{P}(R=\infty)=0$ (simply because $\mathbb{P}(R=\infty) = 1-\mathbb{P}(R<\infty)$) but the other equations are not correct. For instance $\mathbb{P}(R=\infty) = \mathbb{P}(\liminf_n A_n^c)$ does not hold true.

Comment: The question is how to show that $\mathbb{P}(R = \infty) = 0$ using $\mathbb{P}(A_{n} ~\text{infinitely often}) = 1$. All the other steps I have understood. Only Step 4 is my problem

Comment: @love_math $\mathbb{P}(A_n \, \, \text{infinitely often})=1$ tells us, in particular, that for almost every $\omega$ we can find $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\omega \in A_n$ (in fact there are infinitely many such $n$, but we are fine with one). As $A_n \subseteq \{R<\infty\}$ this implies $\omega \in A_n \subseteq \{R<\infty\}$, i.e. $R(\omega)<\infty$.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your effort. I really appreciate that. My thought to proof that $\mathbb{P}(R = \infty) = 0$ is as follows. First I have $\{R=\infty\} = \bigcap_{m \geq 1}A_{n}^{c} \subseteq \bigcup_{n \geq 1}\bigcap_{m \geq n}A_{n}^{c}$. Now I have $\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{n \geq 1}\bigcap_{m \geq n}A_{m}^{c}) = \mathbb{P}(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\inf A_{n}^{c}) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sup A_{n}) = 1 - 1 = 0$. Are my thought correct? (:

Comment: @love_math We only have $\{R=\infty\} \color{red}{\subseteq} \bigcap_{m \geq 1} A_m^c$ (for instance, if $Z_2(\omega)=1$, $Z_3(\omega)=0$, $Z_4(\omega)=1$, $Z_5(\omega)=0$ for some $\omega$, then $R(\omega)<\infty$ but $\omega \in \bigcap_{m \geq 1} A_m^c$ ... this shows that $\bigcap_m A_m^c$ is stricly larger than $\{R=\infty\}$.) Apart from that, your reasoning is correct, I think. (Note that with the correction which I mentioned you still get the desired result $\mathbb{P}(R=\infty)=0$.)